# JSF page jumps to a new page after using the ajax filter method and fails to bind the current object

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I don't use filter from the search area.
[image]
After I clicked zoom icon. It runs as normal.
[image]

But when I use filter from the search area.
[image]
Search area of customer details always returns first data of datatable
[image]

This is part of my codes related to search area of customer list
licenseholder.xhtml

```
<p:commandButton process="@this" 
                                                         title="Details" 
                                                         icon="fa button-icon-color icon-search"
                                                         action="#{licenseHolderAdmin.doShowDetails()}">
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{serviceCustomer}" target="#{licenseHolderAdmin.holderCurrent}" />
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="0" target="#{licenseHolderAdmin.activeTab}" />
                                        </p:commandButton>
```

LicenseholderAdmin.java

```
    public String doShowDetails() {
        if (updateCurrentHolder) {
            this.getHolderCurrent();
        }

        setSelectedLicenses(new ArrayList<License>());
        return "licenseholderdetails";
    }


    public LicenseHolder getHolderCurrent() {
        if (updateCurrentHolder) {
            if (holderCurrent != null
                    && holderCurrent.getCustomerId() != null) {
                holderCurrent = customerDao.update(holderCurrent);
            }
            updateCurrentHolder = false;
        }
        return holderCurrent;
    }
```

CustomerDao.java

```
    @Override
    public LicenseHolder findById(long id) {
        try {
            Query query = em.createQuery("select distinct lh from LicenseHolder lh where customerId = :id");
            Integer intId = (int) id;
            query.setParameter("id", intId);
            return (LicenseHolder) query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Datensatz konnte nicht gefunden werden.", "ID=" + id));
            LOGGER.error("Error while retrieving single customer.");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public LicenseHolder update(LicenseHolder customer) {
        return findById(customer.getCustomerId());
    }
```

This is part of my codes related to Search area of customer details
licenseholder-details.xhtml

```
<p:selectOneMenu class="dropdown"  value="#{licenseHolderAdmin.holderCurrent}"  converter="licenseHolderConverter" >

<f:selectItems value="#{licenseHolderAdmin.getServiceCustomers()}" var="customer"
itemLabel="#{customer.company} (#{customer.customberNumber})" itemValue="#{customer}" />
                                                             
<p:ajax event="change" oncomplete="switchToCustomer()" process="@form" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

LicenseHolderAdmin.java

```
    public List<LicenseHolder> getServiceCustomers() {
        return getHolders();
    }

    public List<LicenseHolder> getHolders() {
        if (holders == null || updateHolderList) {
            holders = customerDao.getAllCustomers();
            updateHolderList = false;
        }
        return holders;
    }
```

CustomerDao.java

```
    public List<LicenseHolder> getAllCustomers() {
        List<LicenseHolder> holders = null;

        try {
            Query query = em.createQuery("select distinct lh from LicenseHolder lh order by COMPANY");
            holders = query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Datensätze konnte nicht geladen werden.", ""));
            LOGGER.error("Error while retrieving all customers.");
        }

        return holders;
    }
```

I have tried f:selectItems to set itemValue="#{customer.customberNumber}". Result doesn't change.
I have also tried f:selectItems to set value="#{licenseHolderAdmin.getHolder(Long id). But I will lost function of query of dropdown. For example.
[image]

I am unfamiliar with JSF. Any advice will be grateful!

Comment: I think that setPropertyActionListener is executed after the action, so server-side you've got the previous value. I suggest separating these operations, moving the action in a remote command, called on complete of commandButton

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you tell me how can I use it onComplete method? I tried f:param. It doesn't work. I don't know how to bind para on Complete :(

Comment: I would try with something like this `<p:commandButton onComplete="showDetail()"> <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{serviceCustomer}" target="#{licenseHolderAdmin.holderCurrent}" /> <f:setPropertyActionListener value="0" target="#{licenseHolderAdmin.activeTab}" /> </p:commandButton> <p:remoteCommand name="showDetail" action="#{licenseHolderAdmin.doShowDetails()}" />`